# Accessing API Management with Internal VNET with custom domain name (getting default IIS page)

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, azure-custom-domain

We have our API Management instance with Internal VNET configuration. I wanted to make the various URLs accessible with a custom domain name. So we issued an internally generated certificate from our on-premise CA. We also uploaded the Root certificate into APIM. To test, I next added the SCM url first Custom domain. However, it seems like when accessing the custom domain you end up at the default IIS page. You cant get to IIS to do Host Headers. So how does one resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had not included the protocol. So it was taking me to port 80. After including https:// it worked fine.